# Sum of all amount of a table field and get the latest last record id

Tags: mysql, database

I need to sum of all amount of a table field and get the latest last record id.

Example:

suppose we have a table tbl_salarypaid having field "paidamount"

Data in table

```
emp_id paidamount rec_added_date
1       500        2015-11-30
1       500        2015-12-31
```

need to get sum(paidamount), rec_added_date something like

```
SELECT sum(paidamount) as total_paid, rec_added_date from tbl_salarypaid WHERE emp_id = 1
```

Expected result:

```
 1000, 2015-12-31

1000 = sum of all paidamount field
2015-12-31 = latest rec_added_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max()`:

```
SELECT sum(paidamount) as total_paid, max(rec_added_date)
FROM tbl_salarypaid
WHERE emp_id = 1
```

Comment: and if require any other field data of last record except date as I know we can use the max function on date field.


like we have another field added_by

emp_id paidamount rec_added_date added_by
1            500        2015-11-30             1b
1            500        2015-12-31             1a


result:



1000, 2015-12-31, 1a

Thanks in advance

Comment: and if require any other field data of last record except date as I know we can use the max function on date field.


like we have another field added_by

        emp_id          paidamount      rec_added_date        added_by
            1            500            2015-11-30             1b
            1            500            2015-12-31             1a

result:

        1000, 2015-12-31, 1a

Comment: @AtulSharma . . . The only reasonable expectation is to get an answer to the question you asked.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as a question, with suitable sample data, desired results, and explanation.